# Reset password email is not sent by Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3

My Devise controller is working fine sending emails, with one exception: sending the reset password instructions email.

When I click on the "Forgot your password?" link, I get the message:

```
You will receive an email with your password reset instructions in a few minutes.
```

But, I do not receive the email. Following is the relevant dump from the log file:

```
Started GET "/password/new.user" for 174.xx.xxx.xx at 2013-04-29 01:28:48 +0000
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#new as 
  BlogPost Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `blog_posts`.* FROM `blog_posts` 
  Rendered devise/_links.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered devise/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/application (23.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_promo_bar.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 51.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
Started POST "/password" for 174.xx.xxx.xx at 2013-04-29 01:30:19 +0000
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"emailaddress@outlook.com"}, "commit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
  BlogPost Load (137.8ms)  SELECT `blog_posts`.* FROM `blog_posts` 
  User Load (82.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'emailaddress@outlook.com' LIMIT 1
  User Load (14.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`reset_password_token` = 'NysDaribCpgNySc5Nmog' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (99.0ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `reset_password_token` = 'NysDaribCpgNySc5Nmog', `reset_password_sent_at` = '2013-04-29 01:30:19', `updated_at` = '2013-04-29 01:30:19' WHERE `users`.`id` = 113
   (60.6ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.text.erb (1.5ms)

Sent mail to emailaddress@outlook.com (133ms)
Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2013 01:30:21 +0000
To: emailaddress@outlook.com
Message-ID: <517dcd2db584b_71bc6778701193@testsite-test.mail>
Subject: testsite Account Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_517dcd2d93927_71bc677870116dc";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



----==_mimepart_517dcd2d93927_71bc677870116dc
Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2013 01:30:21 +0000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <517dcd2d9bfb9_71bc677870117a2@testsite-test.mail>

Hello emailaddress@outlook.com!

A Request to change the password for this account has been received. If this is you, and you still want to change the password, you can do so by clicking on the link below.

<a href="http://test.testsitethefuture.com/password/edit?reset_password_token=NysDaribCpgNySc5Nmog">Change my password</a>

If you didn&#x27;t request this, please ignore this email.


----==_mimepart_517dcd2d93927_71bc677870116dc
Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2013 01:30:21 +0000
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <517dcd2db365a_71bc677870118da@testsite-test.mail>

<p>Hello emailaddress@outlook.com!</p>

<p>A Request to change the password for this account has been received. If this is you, and you still want to change the password, you can do so by clicking on the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://test.testsitethefuture.com/password/edit?reset_password_token=NysDaribCpgNySc5Nmog">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn&#x27;t request this, please ignore this email.</p>


----==_mimepart_517dcd2d93927_71bc677870116dc--

Redirected to http://test.testsitethefuture.com/login
Completed 302 Found in 2520ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/login" for 174.xx.xxx.xx at 2013-04-29 01:30:22 +0000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  BlogPost Load (3.0ms)  SELECT `blog_posts`.* FROM `blog_posts` 
  Rendered devise/_links.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_promo_bar.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 49ms (Views: 35.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Any ideas of what I should be looking for?

## environments/test.rb

```
Myapp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'myapp.com'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 587,
      domain: "myapp.com",
      authentication: "plain",
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      user_name: 'Admin@myapp.com',
      password: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
end
```

Comment: any chance you can post your mailer config please

Comment: You settings in the `config.mail` block in either your `production` or `development` has not been set up correctly.

Comment: If my mailer config is not set up properly, then no emails will go out. All email is going out, except for the password reset.

Answer (score -1):

Check the SMTP Mailer settings in your config file, from log it is showing that mail is sending correctly but it is not delivered, because of SMTP settings problem.

Correct the smtp settings and check the mailer from console

```
Ex:-

Notification.forgot_password("sample@test.com").deliver
```

Comment: See my question, first sentence: My Devise controller is working fine sending emails, with one exception: sending the reset password instructions email. Also, on the development environment, the reset password instructions email is sent fine.

Comment: Yes, I have seen because of that only i told to try the code in console and before that check the smtp settings, if you are using gmail smtp setting please delete reply from mail sending block. Even log shows mail is sending it will not sent the mail to email if smtp settings are wrong. What OS you are using ?

Answer (score -1):

Having the line `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp in config/environment.rb` overrides `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` in config/environments/test.rb.

So, add that line, `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp' from config/environment.rb` and place it in config/environments/test.rb. That allows you to place

`ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test in config/environments/test.rb`.

**Note: You must restart your server for these changes to take effect.**

In config/environment.rb:

```
# Configuration for using SendGrid on Heroku
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => 'app[my app number]@heroku.com',
  :password       => '[something super secret]',
  :domain         => '[let's get this party started!.com]',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Did you read my question? 1) I am not using Heroku. 2) I DO NOT have ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test in my test.rb 3) I already have config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp in my test.rb 4) I am not using SendGrid 5) I do not have anything related to mailing in config/environment.rb

Comment: Yes i read your question try to add **ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp** in **config/environment.rb**. It is similar to your problem. I have created an app on heroku and faced the same problem. Also i have resolved the problem as mentioned above. Please check

Comment: Adding ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp to config/environment.rb does not work, and does not add anything at all, because that line is already in /config/environments/test.rb. Read my question

Comment: Ok change the line to **ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test** in **config/environment/test.rb** and please check. Also add **ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp** in **config/environment.rb**.

Comment: I'm not going for random guesses. I already have an environments/test.rb file. Read it so you can understand why your suggestions do not work.

Comment: It's Ok may be you are stucked with different problem, But the solution worked for me.